# Identifing direction of vehicle movement from image

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, yolo, faster-rcnn

I'm engaged with a research to count the number of vehicles in an image based on the direction of movement. The following is a sample image.

[image]

At the moment I'm using TensorFlow implementation of YOLO and faster-RCNN to count the number of vehicles in a particular image. However, I'm stuck in identifying the movement direction. Any resource or guide is highly appreciated.

Comment: By identifying direction, do you want to classify categories of directions ( like RIGHT, LEFT, SLIGHTLY_RIGHT etc. )? If so mention it in your question.

Comment: @Shubham Panchal : Only the two lanes, such as left and right.

Comment: You can train the model on images categorized as RIGHT and LEFT. Also, we can use a segmentation model to segment the road in the image and then determine its direction.

Comment: I did something similar. You can extend Faster R-CNN (by adding additional FC head) which would determine direction. For that you will need labeled data and to hack google object detection framework.

Comment: @Shubham Panchal: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @carobnodrvo: Thank you. Do you have any work published?

Comment: No, sorry the work was not public. You can just copy-paste stuff from classification task and with minor adjustments you can get it to work.